# How to advertise my android applications?

Tags: android, ads, google-play

There is "advertise app" reference  only for my free applications in Android Developer Console. How to advertise  Android apps for sale? 
Where is the best place to advertise? How it works?
Should I always insert some code to the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, look into In-house ads if you have other apps (i.e. if you use AdMob) and [Tap for Tap](http://tapfortap.com)

Comment: I have just published new apps. I have no sales. Absolutely. "Tap for tap" will not help me. I am ready to pay for ads to start. But where?...

Comment: Make sure your description and title has relevant keywords in it - search will likely bring the most downloads to your app. Also, know that the statistics in the Android Developer Console are delayed by 48 hours or more - I'd wait a week and see how your app is doing.

Other than that, you can use any advertising network, as all you need to do is link to "market://details?id=com.yourcompany.yourapp".

I'd go with AdMob (http://www.google.com/ads/admob/)

Comment: Okay, but as I said admob reference is available only for my free apps. I will try again though. How about TapJoy? Thanks.

Comment: >as all you need to do is link to "market://details?id=com.yourcompany.yourapp"------------ To do what? The site name "market://" is not valid. Thanks.

Comment: BTW AdMob look expensive for start. They require minimum $10 daily.

Comment: There are a ton of websites that will help you with this. http://bit.ly/NfRZ19

Comment: I expected to hear advices with the best sites names to start. I understand that I can Google rather than ask advices from experienced guys. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @EGHDK that's unneeded... but I think Tap for Tap lets you buy credits as well. Other than that AdMob is one of the more popular sites, but eek, it does sound expensive. The market:// URL will only work on Android devices - it opens up a link to the Google Play page.

You can try reading this too: http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2171841/Advertising-Your-Mobile-Apps-on-Google-Just-Got-a-Whole-Lot-Easier

Answer (score 1):

### Google I/O 2012: Google Play: Marketing 101 for Developers:

https://developers.google.com/live/shows/ahNzfmdvb2dsZS1kZXZlbG9wZXJzcg4LEgVFdmVudBibttMCDA/

Comment: unfortunately too cumbersome...

Comment: If you think a talk about Marketing for Developers from Google is cumbersome, then I have some bad news for ya buddy.

Comment: Okay, I will try to look at the video again.